# About inheriting the properties of the array object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to learning inheritance concept in JavaScript.  In this context, I would like to inherit the Array object and add functionalities to it.
The problem that I face here is that `third` method is getting executed correctly, but the `show()` method throws an error, stating that `show()` is not a function.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
Array.prototype = {
    third:function(){
        console.log(a[3]);
    },
    show:function(){
        console.log(a);
    }
};
a.third();
a.show();
```

Comment: Where is the sample code for our reference?

Comment: Please post the sample code.

Comment: This is really _really_ bad because what you're doing is replacing _all_ methods on the Array prototype with your own. Please don't do this.

Comment: @Andy—it actually doesn't work. The *Array.prototype* property has been readonly since at least ECMA-262 ed 3 (though the object itself is writeable so can be extended). ;-)

Comment: @RobG, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code is attempting to replace the built–in prototype (which itself is an Array) with a plain object that only has the properties you assign. Instead of replacing the prototype, add properties to the one that's already there, e.g.

```
Array.prototype.third = function() {
    console.log(a[3]);
}
```

Also, since you create the *a* array before replacing *Array.prototype*, it get's the old prototype, not the new one (if the new one is added at all). Both methods throw errors, not just *show*. If you change the prototype **before** creating *a*, it "works" in browsers that allow overwriting of built–in prototypes. It will not work in ECAMScript ed 3 (or perhaps earlier) implementation or later where *Array.prototype* has attributes:

```
{ [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }
```

so you can't replace it and the object itself has attributes:

```
{ [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }
```

so you can add properties and overwrite built–in methods if you wish.

Note that extending built–in objects is generally warned against, see [*Extending builtin natives. Evil or not?*](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/).

Comment: Also, arrays constructed from array literals don't inherit from `Array.prototype`, they inherit from the internal %ArrayPrototype% that cannot be overwritten by assignments to `Array.prototype` anyway (at least since ES5).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, try this way:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
Array.prototype.third = function () { console.log(this[3]); }
Array.prototype.show = function () { console.log(this); }
array.third();
array.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be adding methods to native prototypes, you really need to put a check in place so that you can be sure you're not overriding anything important. So, to take your example and change it up a little:

```
if (!('third' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.third = function () {
    return this[2];
  };
}

[0, 1, 2, 3].third(); // 2
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/svohx407/)